# Is there any way to change the binding once it has been used?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

wpf application has a data grid with column as TimeStamp. The column data is refreshed every 1 sec.

The default timestamp format is "hh:mm:ss.fff". I need to change the time format to "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss:fff" at runtime.

I have used like

```
timeStampColumn.Binding = new Binding("TimeStamp");
timeStampColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss:fff}";
```

Here timeStampColumn is the data grid column name

But it is throwing exception as 
"Binding canot be used after it has been used".

Comment: there is a high chance that you have to perform some kind of cloning the Binding here. For a simple cloning, we can just clone the resolved source and resolved property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `StringFormat` property before you use the new Binding:

```
var binding = new Binding("TimeStamp");
binding.StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss:fff}";
timeStampColumn.Binding = binding;
```

Or shorter:

```
timeStampColumn.Binding =
    new Binding("TimeStamp")
    {
        StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss:fff}"
    };
```